# Magento 2 - Where are data-bind attributes defined?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

In the file *vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html* there is this code:

```
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
```

Where is `product_url` and `product_name` defined?

How does it know where to get the data from?

Answer (score 1):

The principal is called private content

The customer data library is used store private data in local storage, invalidate private data using customizable rules, and synchronize data with the backend.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php#L94

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php#L97

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js#L178

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html#L69-L78

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html#L10

I've picked out a few values hopefully you should start to recognize and you can see how they are set

But in summary knockout fetches the values from php. Sort of how you have discovered but not quite what you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the layout file where the template *vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html* is getting called, to figure out the block class.

I found one reference in the layout file **vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml**:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default" as="default" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
```

As you can see it uses the block class `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer`, where the methods `getProductName()` and `getProductUrl()` are defined. So calling `product_name` in knockoutjs, leads to the fucntion `getProductName` getting called. Not sure where the logic about this is located though.

```
/**
 * Retrieve URL to item Product
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductUrl()
{
    if ($this->_productUrl !== null) {
        return $this->_productUrl;
    }
    if ($this->getItem()->getRedirectUrl()) {
        return $this->getItem()->getRedirectUrl();
    }

    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $option = $this->getItem()->getOptionByCode('product_type');
    if ($option) {
        $product = $option->getProduct();
    }

    return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
}

/**
 * Get item product name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductName()
{
    if ($this->hasProductName()) {
        return $this->getData('product_name');
    }
    return $this->getProduct()->getName();
}
```